# My /dev/vcs7 is missing - is this by design, or can I create it?

Tags: linux-mint, console

In searching for a way to see the messages on my machine's console (the tty I get when hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) from a shell, it was suggested to me that `/dev/vcs7` was the appropriate place to look.  This seems to work for tty's 1-6 - I can cat `/dev/vcs1` and see the login prompt for the unused tty's.  However, my system has no /dev/vcs7.  There are /dev/vcs and /dev/vcsa for numbers 1-8, plus an unnumbered vcs(a), but no vcs(a)7.

Is this by design?  If not, how can I fix it?

I'm running Linux Mint 17.2, btw.

Comment: It doesn't look by design, my 17.2 has it and I can change to it. Do you start your X session by hand? Have you checked after a reboot? Tried starting 17.2 from CD/USB? Maybe some installed software you run has killed that off.

Comment: The primary X session starts automagically, and I've got the machine set to auto-login as my user (the system seems to disable audio if the physical machine isn't logged in to an X session, and this system is a media server I use to play music).  I control the system through a second session, via vnc.  Running "who -a" shows the X session using tty8 & pts/8, and the vnc X session on pts/4, tty 1-8 unused, and no listing at all for tty7.

Comment: I should add that I can't start the X session manually, because the system runs headless in a closet.  If the power goes out when I'm not home, for instance, I want it to recover on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Linux VT console devices are dynamically allocated.   They appear when they are opened by any process, just `echo >/dev/tty63` will do that.  You might be interested in utilities like [`openvt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/openvt.1.html) / [`deallocvt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/deallocvt.1.html) / [`chvt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/chvt.1.html).

Missing `/dev/vcs7` is probably because Xorg session is using `/dev/tty7` in graphics mode.  Xorg uses the first unused console device found beginning from `/dev/tty1`.  In `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` you would find the following line:

```
[     6.446] (++) using VT number 7
```

And you could see the mode of `/dev/tty7` by [`kbdinfo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/kbdinfo.1.html):

```
# kbdinfo -C /dev/tty7 getmode
graphics
```

If you shut down the Xorg session (by `sudo stop mdm` or something like that, I have no experience with Mint), `/dev/tty7` would become free to use.

Comment: Correct assumption.  @user6081: That is why [Ctrl][Alt][F1-6] gets you a text terminal, but [Ctrl][Alt][F7] brings you the Mint GUI.

Comment: On my machine (I believe this is the Mint default, and possibly Ubuntu, from which Mint is derived) the X session uses tty8.  Grepping Xorg.0.log and using kbdinfo as you described confirms this.  ctrl-alt-F8 gets me the Mint GUI, and ctrl-alt-F7 gets me a text console with a few startup messages still sitting in it.  kbdinfo on tty7 returns mode "text".

Comment: @user6081 On Ubuntu, X runs on tty7 by default.

Comment: Interesting.  So how do you get to the (text) startup console?  Or is tty7 essentially usurped as soon as X starts, and then there's no way back to the startup console?